# What Microsoft calls most commonly confused English words

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Recently and belatedly, I came across this article about what they call the 10 most commonly confused words in English. I happened to find the lead sentence interesting.

Here is the link: https://www.standard.co.uk/lifestyle/london-life/the-10-most-commonly-confused-words-in-the-english-language-according-to-microsoft-a3490606.html

I gave it a try and ended up finding three mistakes in the sentence in question. Microsoft's data was a great help, but I can't find the last one. It's a little frustrating not to find it after all the clues given. Can you find it? If you did, what is it?

The following is the statement in question. The writer says there are four mistakes:

**There's nothing more embarrassing than having someone point out a writing mistake and realizing you've been making it everyday. I mean, it's probably effected your professional relationships for awhile. So take my advise — have someone proofread your report before you submit it to your boss.***

Also, I did research and was wondering why English speakers would rather choose to say "commonly **confused** words" than "commonly **confusing** words" when, in fact, people are confused, not words. That means words **make** people **confused**, words are confusing (to people). I know this is a tricky one and I'd appreciate any help. The word "commonly" can modify both "confusing" and "confused" because it's an adverb.

Comment: Are you confused by the object appearing in the place of the subject? This can happen with a lot of verbs. I broke the window => The window broke.  I think the technical term is "unaccusative verb".

Comment: Tell us the three, so we that our effort is not useless.

Answer (score 2):

The four mistakes are among the ten listed at the bottom of the article:

- **everyday** should be **every day**
- **effected** should be **affected**
- **awhile** should be **a while**
- **advise** should be **advice**

We say the words/phrases are **confused** because people confuse them, that is, they use one where they should use the other.

The errors in themselves do not *cause* much confusion in the listener, so they are not **confusing** anyone.

Comment: The movie is boring. The movie makes you bored. 
The word is confusing. The word makes you confused, not confusing.
Why "confused words" instead of "confusing words"? That's confusing and makes me confused.

Comment: Returning to part of your question *English speakers would rather choose to say "commonly confused words" than "commonly confusing words"*. The noun **word** is preceded by one of the two adjectives **confused** and **confusing**. The words are not confusing (the meaning of the sentences remains clear), they are confused (between two alternative spellings).

Comment: It might help to mention that "confuse" is being used as an attributive verb (I think?) [Identify wrongly; mistake](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confuse) instead of an adjective [Bewildering or perplexing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confusing). Even more confusing, we could say "she was easily confused for her sister", meaning that she and her sister are easy to mistake for each other, and "she and her sister were easily confused", meaning either both were often bewildered, or they were easy to mistake for each other.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still confused. For example, again, Boring is an –ing adjective that describes a thing or person that causes this feeling. Bored is an –ed adjective that describes the person that feels the effect of this feeling. The result is that I know people, not things, are confused. Are you saying things like "words" can be confused?

Comment: That is what Microsoft is saying. Although it is not the words themselves which are confused (being inanimate) but their *usage* which is confused, by the writer.

Comment: @Choe Guevara  People commonly confuse these words, that is, mistakenly use one for another. Thus we say that the words are commonly confused, that is, easily mistaken for words of similar sound or spelling, but different meaning. "being confused" (as applied to the words)  means "being mistaken for a different word" so the words are "commonly confused" because they are often misused.

Comment: If the word in question, confused, is used attributively in this particular context, which doesn't seem to be in line with the more common usage though, then I think it can help non-native English speakers have a better understanding. We could say "commonly misused words" and mean the same thing as "commonly confused words", right?

Comment: That is not the same thing. It is only the spelling that is incorrect, not the usage of the word itself.

Comment: I don't think I'm here to take any issue. I think I know the basics of English, but I thought it was something tricky enough for non-English speaking people and I was just trying to have a better idea about the usage and share it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Both uses are correct, they just mean different things.

Part of the problem is that you are mixing up different senses of the word.

---

> — These words are **confusing**. —

This means that the words cause confusion in people who read them.

From the Merriam-Webster definition of the verb [*confuse*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confuse):

> **3 a** : to make indistinct : BLUR
>   // Stop *confusing* the issue.

In this case, *confusing* is acting as an adjective, assigning the quality of *something that causes confusion* to the noun.

In the same way, you could say this:

> This food is *nausea-inducing*.
>   This exercise is *fatiguing*.

In this particular usage, the people are [*confused*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confused) in the following Merriam-Webster sense:

> **1 a** : being perplexed or disconcerted
>   // the *confused* students
>   **1 b** : disoriented with regard to one's sense of time, place, or identity
>   //The patient became *confused*.

---

> — These words are **confused**. —

This means that the words *themselves* are confused.

However, it doesn't mean confused in the previous sense of *perplexed*.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*confused*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confused):

> **2** : INDISTINGUISHABLE
>   // a zigzag, crisscross, *confused* trail
>   — Harry Hervey
>   **3** : being disordered or mixed up
>   // a contradictory and often *confused* story

In short, the English words are not *perplexed*, but they are instead *mixed up*.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the word "commonly", an adverb that sounds more idiomatic modifying the verb "confuse" than the adjective "confusing".

> These words commonly **confuse** people.  People are commonly **confused** by these words.

We simply don't say something like "these words are commonly *confusing*".  Instead you might use a different adverb like "frequently" or "very".

> These words are frequently confusing

Although this still sounds clumsy to my hears.  Words are either confusing or they aren't.  It's the people who determine the frequency of confusion, e.g.:

> These words are frequently **confused**

to mean "people frequently confuse how to use these words."

It would not be wrong to title the article:

> The 10 most **confusing** words in the English language.

but this focuses on the words themselves, rather than on the *people* who are confused by them.  The article is about how to be a better business writer, so it makes more sense to focus on the human element rather than the linguistic element.

Answer (score -4):

I think you are making distinctions that don't exist in English, in any real practical sense, „commonly confused words“ and „commonly confusing words“ are synonymous and can be used interchangeable. Native speakers would never notice the difference. I doubt even publishing companies would notice the difference. Some professor at a University teaching that there is a difference is simply wrong and likely relying on an a rule invented by some Bishop in the 17th century that bears no relation to reality and no one pays any attention to. „ If you have to be taught something about your own (native) language and how to speak it correctly, the odds are about 100% that what you are being taught is wrong. It has to be taught, because it`s NOT your language. In fact, no language can be that way.“ Naom Chomsky, PhD, Linguistics, Professor Emeritis, MIT

Comment: It's just that I was confused. I wasn't trying to make distinctions. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Too many people here are trying to find distinctions that simply don`t exist in English and perpetually confuse „style“ from „grammar rules.“ We need standard spellings and „grammar“ to publish uniform writings and to teach others the language. But no native speaker speaks „incorrectly.“ That`s simply a myth. Native speakers define what the grammar of a language is. There is no great grammar God in the sky determining how native speakers have to speak. Total nonsense. There`s good style and poor style amongst native speakers, but not „incorrect“ and „correct“ grammar amongst native speakers.

Comment: There are some cases where both are acceptable and there are others where that is not the case as many native English speakers here have pointed out, which is a fact acceptable and yet challenging to learn for speakers of English as a foreign language, I suppose.